# Failed to parse calendar specification systemd

Tags: linux, centos, systemd

Категорически приветствую!

Пытаюсь заставить запускаться некий скрипт каждые 15мин в промежуток между 3-мя и 19-ю часами. Пишу `unit timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=This is the timer to set the schedule for automated renewals

[Timer]
OnBootSec=5min
#OnUnitActiveSec=15min
OnCalendar=*-*-* 03..19:00/15:00
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

В ответ получаю `Failed to parse calendar specification, ignoring: *-*-* 03..19:00/15:00`. Варианты `*-*-* 03..19:00,15,30,45:00`, `03..19:00,15,30,45:00`, `*-*-* 03..19:00:00`, `12..14:10,20,30` возвращают тот же результат.

```
# systemctl --version
systemd 219
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN
# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так работает `OnCalendar=*-*-* 03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19:00/15:00`, хотя в [мануале](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html#) явно указан пример `*-*-* 12..14:10,20,30:00`.